# Transforming a series to an integral with respect to counting measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I'd really appreciate it if somebody could help me understand why we have this with a step-by-step explanation (i.e. in an argument complete way) :

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} {\frac {n} {k^2+nk+1}} = \int \frac {n} {x^2+nx+1} \mathbb{1}_{[1, n]}(x) dm(x) $$ with $ m = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \delta_k $. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to realize that
$$
\int f\,\mathrm d m=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int f\,\mathrm d\delta_k
$$
for any integrable function $f$. This can be achieved by a standard argument, i.e. looking at simple functions and then extending. If $f(x)=n/(x^2+nx+1)$, then

$$
\int f(x) \mathbf{1}_{[1,n]}(x)\,\mathrm dm(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int f(x)\mathbf{1}_{[1,n]}(x)\,\mathrm d\delta_k(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)\mathbf{1}_{[1,n]}(k),
$$
where we have used that $\int f\,\mathrm d\delta_k=f(k)$ which is established by the fact that $f=f(k)$ almost surely with respect to $\delta_k$. Lastly, we use that $\mathbf{1}_{[1,n]}(k)=0$ for $k=0$ and $k\geq n+1$ and obtain
$$
\int f(x) \mathbf{1}_{[1,n]}(x)\,\mathrm dm(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)
$$
which is what we want.

Comment: For a simple function $f : (X, \mathcal A) \to \mathbb R$ we have \begin{eqnarray}\int_X f d\mu & = \sum_{a \in f(X)} a \mu \left( \left\{ f \left(x\right) = a \right\} \right) \\ & =\sum_{a \in f(X)} a \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\delta_k \left\{ f(x) = a \right\} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{a \in f(X)} a \delta_k\left\{f(x) = a\right\} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int f d\delta_k \end{eqnarray}

To show the equality holds true for a $\mu$-measurable positive function we apply Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem and then we can easily extend the equality to $\mathscr{L}_R^1(\mu)$. Right?

Comment: @gpo: Looks fine, yes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: hmm.. I think I made a small mistake : to be able to pass from line 2 to line 3 I think the codomain of $f$ should be $R_+$ so that $a > 0$.

Comment: @gpo: Yes, you're right. You start by showing that it holds for non-negative $f$. Then for a general $f$ you use that $f=f^+-f^-$.